# How to stop or destroy a running Thread

Tags: android

I have one thread class which star in `onCreate` of an activity.

```
 class MyThread extends Thread
 {
      void run()
      {
           //My code which takes time.
      }
 }

 //-------------------------- To run the thread
 MyThread mThread = new MyThread();
 mThread.start();
```

On some external events i need to stop/destroy currently running thread.
And Then i create a new copy of MyThread and call `start` function on the new thread to run it.

But i am not able to destroy/stop the previous running thread.
Is there any API by which we can destroy running thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot destroy...only the android will stop the thread when requires.. you cannot stop or destroy it.. instead try like this..

```
class MyThread extends Thread
 {
  void run()
  {
 while(bool){
       //My code which takes time.
  }
 }
 }
```

//-------------------------- To run the thread

```
   MyThread mThread = new MyThread();
   mThread.start();
```

now when u want to stop the thread... change bool value to false

```
bool=false;
```

now your code doesnt run... and you can start new thread...

Answer (score 5):

The [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method is the accepted way of stopping a running thread, but some implementation details are on you: if your thread is doing IO (or anything else that can throw InterruptedException), it's your responsibility to make sure that you close any resources you have open before you stop your thread.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) indicates why some of the thread functionality present in earlier versions of Java was deprecated, and why Thread.destroy() was never actually implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) insted of Thread, because its known as [**Painless Threading**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in android. Once you implement you don't need to bother about Thread Management.

AsyncTask can easily handle and it's very easy for handling ui.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Thread.interrupt() or any other methods that can throw an exception, you can implement your own stopThread method. In order to do that, you must have a local boolean variable with the name " keepRunning " for example.
If you have a for loop or a while loop inside your working code that takes time, you can check for the boolean, if it's false you break the loop and your code won't be running anymore.

```js
class MyThread extends Thread
 {
      boolean keepRunning = true;
      
      void run()
      {
           //inside your for loop
           if (keepRunning) {
           //keep running code which      takes time.
           }
           
           else break;
      }
      
      void stopThread() {
      keepRunning = false;
      }
 }

 //To run the thread
 MyThread mThread = new MyThread();
 mThread.start();
 
 
 //To stop the thread
 mThread.stopThread();
```

After stopping the thread, you can initialize it again to mThread.

Comment: Will this result in a bunch of threads that do nothing or will GC eventually clean them up?

Comment: @Rob If there's no reference to an instance of this thread then it will be garbage collected as any other java object.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this..

```
 class MyThread extends Thread
 {
      void run()
      {
           //My code which takes time.
      }
 }

 //-------------------------- To run the thread
 MyThread mThread = new MyThread();
 mThread.start();

// PERFORM ALL YOUR OPERATIONS HERE..
mThread.destroy();
```

Comment: do not use Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html .destroy() even more it's `@Deprecated public void destroy() { throw new NoSuchMethodError("Thread.destroy()"); }` in Android

Comment: stop and destroy are deprecated functions. are you saying that i need to implement smiler functionality?