# Interrupt looper in a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

hi mate i have a thread with this code

```
private final class Consumer extends Thread {

    public boolean running;

    public Handler consumerHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        consumerHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Consumer-> " + msg.obj);
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();

    }

}
```

My activity create a thread T of type Consumer and call start on it.
How can the activity stop the thread T ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running message loop will not normally *exit* the loop unless an exception is thrown or you've call the `quit()` method. Have a look at DOC - [Be sure to call quit() to end the loop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop%28%29).

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      consumerObj.consumerHandler.quit(); 
      super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: very thanks ! so i only call  quit() on the handler of thread that use looper ?

Comment: For future reference - this was the closest to my question "will thread.interrupt() stop a Looper thread?".  After reading this and several other answers, I decided to investigate this.  Looper is a Java-layer facade for an underlying Linux syscall called epoll, which is a scalable I/O event notification mechanism.  If you check out the AOSP source, you'll find that loop() has a call to the native layer, where eventually a blocking call to epoll happens on the pthread associated with the Java thread.  tl;dr Looper never checks isInterrupted(), so make sure you call stop()!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

One comment above said Looper does not check for `isInterrupted()`. I tried to convince mine by calling `Thread.interrupt()` and adding it inside the loop:

```
        if (isInterrupted()) {
            socket.close();
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
        } else {
            Looper.loop();
        } 
        //some exit code.
```

I also called myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0) to do one loop and catch the `interrupt`, but no sign of running exit code. On debug the Message did not even arrive at the queue; 

Im not sure if excited or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(Consumer != null) {
   Thread thread = Consumer;
   Consumer = null;
   thread.interrupt();
}
```

or have a condition inside

```
public void run() {
   while(running) {

   }
}
```

to stop thread set `running = false;`

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737420/how-to-stop-or-destroy-a-running-thread)